# Checkbox Images with Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Could someone please help with the following WPF - I am having an issue with being able to bind a known image name to a converter, to be able to have a checkbox show images rather than the checkbox.

Here are my static resources:

```
<converter:FilePathToImage  x:Key="FileNameToImage" />
<system:String x:Key="ToggledOFFImagePath">ToggledOFF.png</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="ToggledONImagePath">ToggledON.png</system:String>
```

Here is my checkbox style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="partRRCheckbox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="{Binding Path={StaticResource ToggledOFFImagePath}, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToImage}}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path={StaticResource ToggledONImagePath}, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToImage}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

An object of the type `System.String` cannot be applied to a property that expects the type `System.Windows.PropertyPath`.

Here is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = null;

    if (value is string)
    {
        string name = (string)value;
        bitmapImage = ImageConverters.FileToBitmapImage(name.TrimEnd());
    }

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

I have tried a lot of different things to get this to work, and nothing I have tried seems to be able to show the images. The problem is, I need the ability to have the image in the same folder as all of my other images, which belongs to a different project (resource project). I have bound to other things in the project using this, but not with static resources. With strings that were part of the object I was binding. This is my first time utilizing a static resource of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=net-5.0) property on a `Binding` is used to specify the property path in a bound object.

> Each binding typically has these four components: a binding target object, a target property, a binding source, and a path to the value in the binding source to use.

If you use a static resource for binding, use [`Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.source?view=net-5.0), e.g.:

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource ToggledONImagePath}, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToImage}}
```

If you adapt your style like this, it should work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="partRRCheckbox">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ToggledOFFImagePath}, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToImage}}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
               <ContentPresenter/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource ToggledONImagePath}, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToImage}}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: IT SURE DID! Oh my gosh, I can't believe it was that simple, I rewrote this code SO many times trying to get this to work properly. Thank you a million times!